# Whay I insert 1700 documents but ES makes ~30000

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

I insert by fluentd 1700 uniq documents. But ES display ~30000 total.
If I search  one then ES provides 30.
It means each multiplied even not double but ~30. Why?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

DATE=`date "+%Y-%m-%d" --date "1 days ago"`
dos2unix /home/storage/pm/pm_report.all-.$DATE.csv
cat /home/storage/pm/pm_report.all-.$DATE.csv | awk -F , '{ if ( substr($2, 1, 2) == "20" ) print $0 }' > /var/log/report.csv
exit 0
```

Comment: Could you provide code your using to insert documents into ElastichSearch?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/bash

DATE=`date "+%Y-%m-%d" --date "1 days ago"`
dos2unix /home/storage/pm/pm_report.all-.$DATE.csv
cat /home/storage/pm/pm_report.all-.$DATE.csv | awk -F , '{ if ( substr($2, 1, 2) == "20" ) print $0 }' > /var/log/report.csv
exit 0

Comment: today new index have not 30k but 146k documents total count for new index. where is the problem ?